# Materilaize css breaking primeng rendering of input field. How do I fix this css?

Tags: css, materialize, primeng, primeng-datatable

I have the following code:

```
<div class="container" style="width:100%;">
<div class="ui-widget-header" style="padding:4px 10px;border-bottom: 0 none">
    <i class="fa fa-search" style="margin:4px 4px 0 0"></i>
    <input #gb type="text" pInputText size="50" placeholder="Global Filter">
</div>

<p-dataTable [value]="cars" [globalFilter]="gb">
    <p-column field="vin" header="Vin"></p-column>
    <p-column field="year" header="Year"></p-column>
    <p-column field="brand" header="Brand"></p-column>
    <p-column field="color" header="Color"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>

</div>
```

My component has:

```
  cars = [{
    'vin': 'von',
    'year': '1990',
    'brand': 'Audi',
    'color': 'blue'
  },{
    'vin': 'another',
    'year': '2050',
    'brand': 'Honda',
    'color': 'silver'
  }
  ]
```

This should be fine, but the problem is I want to use primeng with materializecss. Is there a way I can make it so that for the input box, it does not use materializecss's styling and preserves what primeng already has? At this point, the search box looks messed up with the magnifying glass being above the input field and not inline.

[image]

Its supposed to look like this:

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If materalizecss overrides same class that primeng uses, you could just load them in different order, first materalizecss then primeng css. This will ensure that primeng css will override same classes materalize defines.

Find out which class materalize overrides and try to work on that.

**Edit**

I think this plnkr provides an example of your problem

http://plnkr.co/edit/6ptJJw8z9fOgHAAfSv4u?p=preview

Here is how you can fix it

When I open developer tools and select the input box that I want to examine, 
it shows me that materalize.css has a class as follows

[image]

As you can see here, this css class has highest priority and overrides primeng class. Also, it gives a hint that is `:not(.browser-default)` pseudoclass.
So if you give your input `browser-default` class, this rule won't apply.

Check this plnkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/hTa2yxNZJP2Z8p91tQ9t?p=preview

All I did is to add browser-default class to the input

```
<input #gb type="text" class="browser-default" pInputText size="50" placeholder="Global Filter">
```

Comment: I do have that load order, but it still looks broken... in the chrome inspector if I "uncheck" certain materialize css styles, then things look better, though I am not sure how to override this for the primeng component.

Comment: Is this plnkr an example of your problem?

http://plnkr.co/edit/AyrU5SMWsu8c004mWROq?p=preview

Comment: Yes, that plnkr example illustrates what the probelm is.

Comment: I did... though it looks like the problem persists... not sure what is going on. When I stick it in, it didn't look like it changed anything... am not sure if there is something overriding it.

Comment: Turned out to be a version mismatch, after updating the version it works like the plunkr. Upvoted.